# What if the angle between these two unit vectors?

Tags: vectors, angle

We know that $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ are unit vectors along $x$-axis and $y$-axis respectively. So angle between them is $90°$.

But let $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ be unit vectors such that $\vec{a}-\sqrt{2}\vec{b}$ is also a unit vector? How do we determine the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ ?

Comment: If two vectors be unit, we can't conclude that the angle between them is $90$.

Comment: @MyGlasses where did I say that the angle between any two unit vectors is 90°?

Comment: Sorry, the diction of your statement shows that.

Answer (score 1):

If $a - \sqrt{2} b$ is a unit vector, then the inner product
\begin{equation*}
\langle a - \sqrt{2}b, a - \sqrt{2}b \rangle = ||a - \sqrt{2} b||^{2} = 1.
\end{equation*}

My suggestion would be to work out the inner product, first using bilinearity, and then using the relationship between the inner product of two vectors, their magnitudes, and their angles.

Answer (score 0):

The vector $a-\sqrt{2}b$ is unit so $|a-\sqrt{2}b|^2=1$ that is
$$1=(a-\sqrt{2}b).(a-\sqrt{2}b)=a.a-2\sqrt{2}a.b+2b.b=2-2\sqrt{2}a.b$$
this concludes that $a.b=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. The angle between $a$ and $b$ is
$$\cos\theta=\frac{a.b}{|a||b|}=\frac{a.b}{|a||b|}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
finally
$$\color{blue}{\theta=\arccos\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The vector $a-\sqrt{2}b$ is unit vector so $|a-\sqrt{2}b|^2=1$ therefore
$$1=(a-\sqrt{2}b).(a-\sqrt{2}b)=a.a-2\sqrt{2}a.b+2b.b=3-2\sqrt{2}a.b$$
Implies that $a.b=\dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{2}}$. So angle between $a$ and $b$ is
$$\cos\theta=\frac{a.b}{|a||b|}=\frac{a.b}{|a||b|}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
finally
$$\color{green}{\theta=\arccos\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = π/4}$$